# Receiving money from friend: PayPal?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

I made some hotel + travel arrangements through the Net, and a friend needs to pay me back.

We both have PayPal accounts, but I've never used it to receive money. So far, I only used PayPal to send donations or pay for shareware by using the credit card linked to my account.

Does PayPal charge money...

- when a PayPal user sends money to another PayPal user/account directly, ie. without going through a bank/credit card at any time?
- when transferring the money from my PayPal account to my bank/credit card?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not indicate your country of residence or that of your friend. The fees would depend on this.

Normally within US transfer of funds between paypal acounts is free. Transfering Outside there is a small charge.
Further if when you withdraw the money to your bank account there would be a small fee.

Refer to *[When it's free and when there's a fee](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=marketing_us/fees)* on Paypal for more details.

Comment: Ask your friend when sending you the money, to select the personal tab after clicking the send money option and then select "Gift" option on that to avoid paying any fees.

Other than that you can use the link from Dheer to read additional information on fees for paypal

Comment: Sorry. It was a general question (in case I need to send/receive money to/from someone located elsewhere), but we're both in France. I'll check the links, thanks.

Comment: "TRANSFERRING MONEY Usually free : Sending money to friends and family is also free for you and the recipient when you fund the transfer with your bank account." : I don't understand what they mean with "when you fund the transfer with your bank account". I just want the friend to log on to PayPal, transfer money to my PayPal account, and I'll transfer the money to the bank card linked to my PayPal account.

Comment: They mean that if your friend uses his bank (e.g., checking) account that is linked to Paypal, then there will be no fees charged.  If they use a credit card, you will likely be charged for the credit card fees (In the US, I think it's something like $0.30 + 3.5% of the transaction, but it may be different in France).  To withdraw funds from your account, I believe you have to have a bank account linked to your Paypal, and it may take 2-3 days for the transfer to complete.

Comment: A friend just checked: Some banks charge for bank-to-bank transfers, and PayPal takes 10 days (!) to send money to another PayPal account. I can't believe people still have to rely on cash and checks to send each other money :-/

Comment: Ten days is probably a worst case scenario. I recently sent money to my daughter with Paypal and it took less than a day.That was pulling money from my checking account and depositing to her Paypal account.